# How to tune Neo4j performance when filtering related node?

Tags: neo4j

The following Cypher query is taking a very long time to execute in my database:

```
MATCH (foo:Foo{field:'abc'})-[:has]->(bar:Bar)
MATCH (bar)-[:isAt]->(baz:Baz)
WHERE baz.field <= 7000000 AND bar.field > 2
RETURN DISTINCT bar ORDER BY baz.field, bar.field LIMIT 50
```

I have around 130 million nodes with the `:Foo` label, 50 million nodes with the `:Bar` label, and 8k with the `:Baz` label and I have indexes on `field` for all these labels.

Running a simple `MATCH (foo:Foo{field:'abc'}) RETURN bar LIMIT 50` works fast as expected, so I imagine the first query is taking a lot of time because it needs to relate with the other nodes and filter them as well.

Is there anything I can do to make this query faster, even if it involves changing the Graph model?

EDIT: Very important thing I forgot to mention: there are around 2 million `:Foo` nodes with `field: 'abc'`.

Comment: Add this keyword: PROFILE on the first line of your query and give the result to us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: Filter bar right at the start

```
MATCH (foo:Foo{field:'abc'})-[:has]->(bar:Bar) WHERE bar.field > 2
WITH bar 
MATCH (bar)-[:isAt]->(baz:Baz) WHERE baz.field <= 7000000 
RETURN DISTINCT bar, baz ORDER BY baz.field, bar.field LIMIT 50
```

Option #2: Using EXISTS because foo is not returned

```
MATCH (bar)-[:isAt]->(baz:Baz) 
WHERE baz.field <= 7000000 AND bar.field > 2
AND EXISTS( (:Foo{field:'abc'})-[:has]->(bar) )
RETURN DISTINCT bar, baz ORDER BY baz.field, bar.field LIMIT 50
```

Question:

How many categories/types Bar has? Let's say bar has three items like red, blue, green. You can change :has into :has_red, :has_blue, :has_green so your relationships to your 50M Bar is split into 3.